# Script destroying element without being told to - why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A strange problem. I've been writing a very simple JS game as a demo. The problem is, one of the functions destroys the container element without me asking it to (the function creates another element within the container - but I've done this before with no problem).

Solutions greatly appreciated - I certainly don't know.

JSFiddle here: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/t5TDM/3/)

The `make()` function is the one you're looking at - the others don't work at the moment but I haven't properly looked at those so don't worry about them.

Comment: Either you computer is possessed, or you are asking it to destroy that element. I'm leaning towards the latter.

Comment: If I am I'm doing so implicitly - there's no `$(container).remove()` line or anything to the same effect.

Comment: Why do you have a script in the html window in your fiddle as well as in the JS window? You seem to be trying to create to `Bubbles` and if you look at the console, you are getting errors.

Comment: @CaolanEvans Please include the relevant code directly in the question.

Comment: @CaolanEvans aids in additional downvotes too.

Comment: @CaolanEvans It adds 0 clarity if i can't get to jsfiddle or if jsfiddle servers go down (which has happened in the past.) that's why you can't post a question containing a jsfiddle link without code. your question barely gets by due to `make()` at the bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't remove the canvas, you turned it into the bubble. The whole problem starts with this line:

```
var bubble = $(_bubbles.canvas).append("<div></div>");
```

it is identical to:

```
var bubble = _bubbles.canvas;
bubble.append("<div></div>");
```

To solve your problem, swap it around:

```
var bubble = $("<div></div>").appendTo(_bubbles.canvas);
```

An alternative would be:

```
var bubble = $("<div></div>");
$(_bubbles.canvas).append(bubble);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t5TDM/5/

Comment: +1 I do also had an doubt about using `append` and `appendTo`.. but it is does here, great.